# How do I pass an ordinal position into the update document in Pymongo for an $inc update

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a document with a nested array of documents that do not have ids

```
_id: adsjfdsau7Hukad,
'nested':[{ a:'123456',b:'zzzzzzzzz'},
          {a:'788123',b:'6yuuuuuu'},
          {a:'123456',b:'ooo998uj'}]
```

I want to increment a new property, 'c' in a specified element of an identified document. For instance:

```
db.collection.update({_id:'adsjfdsau7Hukad'},{$inc:{'nested.2.c':1}})
```

This works when I can explicitly write the element ordinal position identifier.  But, I need to pass a variable for the element ordinal position, and I have not found a way to do so.  I tried this:

```
var num = 4 ## as example
db.collection.update({_id:'adsjfdsau7Hukad','nested.$': num},{$inc:{'nested.$.c':1}})
```

but this does not seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to generate your key programmatically:

In the shell:

```js
var num = 4;
var inc = {};
inc['nested.' + num + '.c'] = 1;
db.collection.update({_id: 'adsjfdsau7Hukad'}, {$inc: inc})
```

In pymongo:

```py
num = 4
db.collection.update(
    {'_id': 'adsjfdsau7Hukad'},
    {'$inc': {'nested.' + str(num) + '.c': 1}})
```

Comment: That's exactly what I thought **should** work.  But I've tried 8 ways form Sunday and it just doesn't work.  I executed the shell version you suggested and get the following:   `Mon Aug 05 19:46:33.395 JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token +  `

Comment: That edit worked for the shell.  Still having problems with the Python, but it may be because I'm more used to PHP.